# Contains text in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to capture an Error which would restart my program and change proxy but I am unable to catch the error as its stored like this and classes are dynamically named :

```
<p class="g4Vm4">By signing up, you agree to our <a target="_blank" href="https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870">Terms</a> . Learn how we collect, use and share your data in our <a target="_blank" href="https://help.instagram.com/519522125107875">Data Policy</a> and how we use cookies and similar technology in our <a target="_blank" href="/legal/cookies/">Cookies Policy</a> .</p>
```

so I am trying to catch the xpath by this function but I am un able to do so.

```
def has_error(browser):
        try:            #/*[contains(text(), 'technology')]/html/body/span/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/p"
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body//*[contains(text(),'technology')]")
            return False
        except: return True
        if not has_error(browser):
            print('Error found! , aborted!')
            browser.quit()
            os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Handle dynamic element use `WebDriverwait` and following `Xpath` Startegy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions


element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//p[contains(.,"technology")]')))
print(element.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the source of the web-page contains special text.

```
if 'By signing up, you agree to our ' in browser.page_source:
    pass
    # TODO Exception
```